# Bootstrap buttons align and flow in responsive design

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

My button groups looks just perfectly on wide screens (computer LCDs) and in horizontal layout:

[image]

And becomes ugly in portrait layout (or when computer browser is resized strongly):

[image]

Here is the code (cut off dropdown menu part):

```
<div class="well well-small">

    <a id="btnInfo" href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Device Info</a>

    <a id="btnAcrid" href="#" class="btn btn-info">Acrid Blog</a>

    <div class="btn-group">
      <a class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-inverse" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
        Dropdown
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
    </div>

</div>
```

What is the best practice to work around such problem? The only thing, that comes to my mind is to use Boostrap class `.visible-phone`, for example, like that:

```
<div style="margin: 5px" class="visible-phone"></div>
```

But I have a strong feeling, that there must be a more professional ways to solive this case.

**EDIT**: I'm looking for a solution for button set as shown. So using block buttons is not an option. They're looking ugly (screen-wide long) on portraits and `.btn-block` does not seems to work on dropdowns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `class="btn-block"` to the buttons for a phone-layout. So you will see them 100% width in a row.

Look at here:
http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons

Comment: Just a heads up, `class=btn-block` should actually be `class="btn-block"` (note the quotation marks)

Comment: True @davblayn , I reformulated the answer and forgot the quotation marks.

Comment: That's okay. I couldn't suggest an edit because It was a two character difference

Comment: No, that is not an option. First of all, block buttons looks just ugly on phone layout (about 300-400 pixels long) and second of all, I want a solution that will work for all buttons, including dropdown button, which you can see in example image. And either I'm blind or `.btn-block` class doesn't work with dropdowns. There are some tips on SO, on how to force dropdowns to acts like block buttons, but then again, their just looks ugly on portrait layouts.